# Addressing based on centrelines, or assigned at parcel creation?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, geocoding, reverse-geocoding

I'm still pretty green when it comes to GIS and using ArcGIS products, so hopefully this question doesn't sound too dumb.

I am just wondering what the best way to go about assigning addresses to newly created parcels within a new subdivision.

Should I create the road centrelines and add in the FromLeft, ToLeft, etc. attributes, and assign addresses based on this, or should I assign an address when the subdivision is created, and update the centreline attributes to correspond with the created parcels.

Comment: What type of data is your primary data? Are you managing linear roadway features or polygonal parcel features? What other address data do you maintain currently?

Comment: What do you mean by "primary data"? I am managing roadway features as well as polygonal parcel features. We have been using centrelines for addressing for all of our rural areas (using a GPS point to get an address using reverse-geocoding), but we haven't addressed any subdivision since we took over from a third-party contractor,

Comment: I presume both linear and polygonal features are feeding into a geocoding system for use in other applications. Personally, I would associate the addresses with the Parcel features. A point within/at the center of the parcel is more likely going to be of higher positional accuracy than an interpolated feature along a line segment.

Comment: So, just to clarify, I should be creating the parcels, adding a point in the middle of the parcel, and giving it an address based on the centreline?

Comment: Do you normally create parcels in the normal course of work? GIS is such a diverse profession, would you mind sharing some more information regarding your use case? I want to help you find the "best fit" for this problem, but I'm not entirely clear on how you're going to use the data - or how this work fits into the routine work you perform - to give you a solid recommendation on how to tackle this problem. A good rule of thumb is to only maintain data (instead of pull from outside source) if it truly benefits your workflow. Deal with real estate? Parcels. Routing & transit? Roadways.

Comment: We deal mostly with the parcels, as I work for a rural municipality in Canada, so we have are the only ones creating and maintaining the tax parcels, as well as the roadways. I would say that dealing with the parcels themselves are our biggest concern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you mentioned in the comments, the Parcel data is your office's responsibility. I'm going to assume that you are only tasked with the spatial data portion of the newly subdivided lots and that another office in the municipality (Planning or Taxation, perhaps) handles assessment and land records management. If that is the case, I would consider adding a field to the parcel data to be the "descriptive location" which can be used as an address until land records, assessment, or the Post Office assigns an actual mailing address to the newly created lot. "Descriptive location" would also help in the cases where your office would want to have an address analogue, but said lot would not normally be addressable (e.g. vacant wood lot, far from a road).

If you'd like, I can expand upon this further with how it is often done on the east coast of the US.

Comment: We have it set up so that I would be assigning addressing when the parcel is created based on subdivision plans (since no one else has any GIS experience, I am in the position of pulling mainly tabular data from other offices in the Municipality and associating it with a polygonal parcel within ArcMap.) I was talking with some co-workers, and have decided that we should create the addresses as I build them within ArcMap.